# Rotate GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, glsurfaceview

I am showing 2D Image on GLSurfaceView and Want to rotate it with specific degree (ie. 180 ,75,360...)

I written following code in touch event.( Here GPUImageView extends GLSurfaceView ) and I am getting value in variable rotationDegree from my Rotate Gesture Detector class which process two finger rotation gestures. Below code rotate the GLSufaceview but content / iamge shown in GLSurfaceView remain same (not rotating inside it). android have examples but they are for 3D and not rotation with degree.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        rotationDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        /* Rotate View Here */
        GPUImageView.this.setRotation(rotationDegree);
        requestRender();
        return true;
    }
```

I have my custom rotation detector class which dispatches events related to two finger rotation

```
    private class RotateListener extends RotateGestureDetector.SimpleOnRotateGestureListener
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onRotate(RotateGestureDetector detector)
        {
            rotationDegree -= detector.getRotationDegreesDelta();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that actually sets `rotationDegree`? Within the code you have shown for this particular function it is constant.

Comment: I added code how I modifify rotationDegree variable. rotationDegree is variable which is modified when two finger rotation is done which is detected by my custom RotationGestureDetecter Class.As I said rotation works fine but it does only rotate outer view internal content remain on same position.

Answer (score 0):

you can also rotate the surface view via the ModelMatrix..

```
onDrawFrame()
{
Matrix.tramslateM(yourModelMatrix,offsetValue,translationInx,translationInY,translationInZ);
Matrix.rotateM(yourModelMatrix,offsetValue,andgle in degrees,inDirectionX,inDirectioY,inDirectionZ);
}
```

Comment: can you explain it with more code as I am not from OpenGL Background need some more code how to use modelMatrix and manipulate code you have shown here.

Comment: in your GLSurfaceView code if you have Renderer class then you must have three method overriden i.e onSurfaecChanged(),onSurfaceCreated() and onDrawFrame() with some parameters.i have shown you the code for rotation of the GL Surface View screen and translation in this code.